# How to Check if a link string contains a word? (PHP)

Tags: php

i'm wondering how to check if a string like : http://www.reddit.com/xxx/x/xxx contains the word : reddit.com

that string could contains or not contains reddit.com

and if it contains , it execute my function : itsReddit()

maybe with preg match? or something like this?

Please i don't want a link for tutorial, i only need a php code for this, & THANKS soo much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if(strpos($your_link, 'reddit.com') !== FALSE) itsReddit();
```

Comment: I don't know what the purpose of this is for, but wouldn't this make it easy to just fudge a link (like `http://somemaliciouslink.com/?reddit.com`)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$input = 'http://www.reddit.com/xxx/x/xxx';
if ( false!==stripos($input, 'reddit.com') ) {
  //itsReddit();
  echo 'reddit';
}
```

Or if you want to test if *the host* is reddit.com

```
$input = 'http://www.reddit.com/xxx/x/xxx';
$host = parse_url($input, PHP_URL_HOST);

if ( false!==stripos($host, 'reddit.com') ) {
  //itsReddit();
  echo 'reddit';
}
```